# AutoPointer with objects not allocated on heap

Tags: c++

Auto pointer internally calls delete on the object that it points to once it goes out of scope. This works fine if we assign an object that is created on the heap. But if i try to assign an object that's not created on heap it crashes as delete is called twice. First by the auto_ptr itself and second as the object goes out of scope its destructor is called again. 
As shown below,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class sample
{
      public:
             sample() { puts("sample"); }
             ~sample() { puts("~sample"); }
};

int main()
{
    sample sObj;
    auto_ptr<sample> samplePtr(&sObj);
}
```

Does that mean we can use auto_ptr to hold only the objects that are created on the heap?

Comment: You are basically right, but even better idea would be not to use `auto_ptr` (but rather `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` etc.): it's a proven source of mistakes and deprecated in the new standard.

Comment: Why do you want to store a stack object in an `auto_ptr`? The whole point of smart pointer classes like `auto_ptr` is that they delete their owned objects in the end...

Comment: @Vlad, unique_ptr is a better general purpose replacement, use shared_ptr only when you need too.

Comment: @111111: you're right, I've added this to the comment.

Comment: *it crashes as delete is called twice* No, it crashes because auto_ptr tries to a `delete` on a pointer which is not allocated using `new`, not because of double deletion.

Comment: @Naveen - I get a call to the destructor once. delete calls the destructor first and then frees the memory. So while freeing memory it crashes as the memory was not allocated by the dynamic memory managemen. Right?

Comment: @RajeevMehta: Yes, but you need to understand there is a difference between calling the destructor and `delete`. When a object allocated on stack goes out of scope, its destructor is called but it is not through `delete`. `delete` is called only for the memory allocated using `new`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, exactly, you can only use `auto_ptr` for heap-allocated objects. The technical reason is `auto_ptr` destructor calls `delete` and calling `delete` on objects not allocated on heap is *undefined behavior* which can crash the heap, run a destructor multiple time, anything else you shouldn't count on and shouldn't speculate about.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer - yes.

It means you pass responsibility to manage the memory to the `auto_ptr`. But if you're creating objects in automatic storage, that responsibility lies with the runtime, so it's not yours to give away.

Answer (score 2):

Objects of automatic storage duration (what you called "on the stack") are cleaned up automatically. `auto_ptr` exists to facilitate the clean up of objects allocated with `new` (it calls `delete` on the pointer). It makes no sense to use `auto_ptr` with objects of automatic storage duration, because they are not allocated with `new`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use std::auto_ptr you can only hold objects created on the heap.

But if you use for example boost::shared_ptr you can specify an deleter which will
be called when the object leaves scope. So if you reference an object on stack you can
use a custom deleter which actually does nothing.
See [boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) for details

std::auto_ptr is as of C++11 deprecated
See [C++11 std::auto_ptr deprecated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#General-purpose_smart_pointers)

Answer (score 1):

Does that mean we can use `auto_ptr` to hold only the objects that are created on the heap?
Yes.
Automatic objects are destroyed automatically and hence they don't need any wrapper like a smart pointer.

Note though that You can use, `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` which gives you facility to call your custom deletor function. You could use custom memory allocators instead of `new` by using this custom deletor functionality.

`auto_ptr` is deprecated and C++ standard suggests `unique_ptr` to be the superior alternative.

Comment: You mean `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` for objects allocated on the heap (where you'd formerly use `auto_ptr`), right? And not for objects in automatic storage.